# Docker Insufficient permissions to set thread priority

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm getting this error when running a multi-threading library on Docker.

```
Insufficient permissions to set thread priority. Please retry as root.
```

I have therefore tried to run the image with the `-u` option, that specifies that the root user with id 0 be used to run `/bin/bash`:

```
docker run -u 0 --rm -it img bash
```

or

```
docker run -u root --rm -it img bash
```

The same happens if I run the command instead of bash like

```
docker run -u root --rm -it img './threading_test'
```

But actually it does not solve the permissions problem, and still getting the error.

**[UPDATE]**

Adding the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
MAINTAINER Loreto Parisi loretoparisi@gmail.com
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libcap2-bin
COPY ./src .
CMD ["./y-cruncher"]
```

I have added the `libcap2-bin` since command `capsh` was not installed by default. As suggested the `capsh --print` capabilities check will return

```
root@d24d02a2ee8c:/# capsh --print
Current: = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_nice,cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap+eip
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_nice,cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
uid=0(root)
gid=0(root)
groups=
```

The run command was `docker run --rm -it --cap-add=sys_nice y-cruncher` since I have set `CMD ["./y-cruncher"]` in the `Dockerfile` by defaults.

Comment: have you tried to run it with --cap-add=sys_nice ?

Comment: doing `docker run --rm -it -u root --cap-add=sys_nice cmd` I get the same error: `Insufficient permissions to set thread priority. Please retry as root.`

Comment: maybe you need more than sys_nice ? i think `--privileged`  will solve your issue but i am trying to identify what is the needed linux capabilities to add it instead run as privileged container

Comment: Please provide `docker info`.

Comment: Here is `docker info` result: https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/48c4eb79be1098bc803b31a23cf8826d

Comment: Try with `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` or with mentioned `--privileged`. Could you provide used multi-threading code example?

Comment: @JanGaraj the library is `y-cruncher` source code - http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher  - I just copy the sources on `Ubuntu 18.04` and try to run `./y-cruncher`

Comment: what is your host os ? i am running manjaro

Comment: Can you please share your Dockerfile?

Comment: @MostafaHusseinaccording to the `docker info` he shared, he is using Mac.

Comment: @loretoparisi what is the output of `capsh --print` from your host itself ?

Comment: @JanGaraj If it helps, y-cruncher is showing this warning because `pthread_setschedparam()` is failing with `errno == EPERM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you need to give the container `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability to be able to set the priorities.

> y-cruncher needs to run with root user otherwise the error message will be raised

A test before giving `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability:

```
Launching y-cruncher...
================================================================
Insufficient permissions to set thread priority. Please retry as root.
Further messages for this warning will be suppressed.
Checking processor/OS features...
Required Features:
    x64, ABM, BMI1, BMI2, ADX,
    SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2,
    AVX, FMA3, AVX2
Parsing Core -> Handle Mappings...
    Cores:  0-3 
Parsing NUMA -> Core Mappings...
    Node  0:  0-3 
y-cruncher v0.7.7 Build 9499                ( www.numberworld.org )
Copyright 2008-2020 Alexander J. Yee      ( a-yee@u.northwestern.edu )
```

A test after giving `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability with: `--cap-add=sys_nice ubuntu:latest`

```
Launching y-cruncher...
================================================================
Checking processor/OS features...
Required Features:
    x64, ABM, BMI1, BMI2, ADX,
    SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2,
    AVX, FMA3, AVX2
Parsing Core -> Handle Mappings...
    Cores:  0-3 
Parsing NUMA -> Core Mappings...
    Node  0:  0-3 
y-cruncher v0.7.7 Build 9499                ( www.numberworld.org )
Copyright 2008-2020 Alexander J. Yee      ( a-yee@u.northwestern.edu )
```

> It may worth mentioning to ensure that the kernel itself has the required capability enabled using `capsh --print` however `CAP_SYS_NICE` should be exist on the host by default

Comment: Thank you, so the right run command would be `docker run --rm -it --cap-add=sys_nice y-cruncher bash "./y-cruncher"`

Comment: Okay, I assume it should work, but `y-cruncher` stil gives back that error in the `Dockerfile` above. I have checked the capabilities as well and update the post above. Thank you for your investigations.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an app issue. Non docker execution has the same problem:

```
$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
$ ./y-cruncher-static/y-cruncher | grep 'Insufficient'
Insufficient permissions to set thread priority. Please retry as root.
```

Docker execution:

```
$ docker run --rm -v $PWD/y-cruncher-static:/y-cruncher-static --privileged --security-opt seccomp=unconfined -ti ubuntu bash -c "/y-cruncher-static/y-cruncher | grep 'Insufficient'"
Insufficient permissions to set thread priority. Please retry as root.
```

Debug info:

```
$ capsh --print
Current: = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,35,36+ep
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,35,36
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
uid=0(root)
gid=0(root)
groups=0(root)
$ uname -a
Linux dockerhost 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 26 15:12:11 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Are you using MacOS too ? If thats the case then its an issue with macos in specific

Comment: No, Centos 7 VM in my case.

Comment: Weird , I didn't have the problem after giving sys_nice cap only

Comment: @MostafaHussein so this confirms that it is not an app related issue, right?

Comment: No, I don't think so I have tested it twice one with docker which added to my answer and the second one on my machine itself with non-root. however when running a non-root user i will always see the error message even with using setcap on the binary, the only way was to use a root user

Comment: i will try to test it later using centos vm but i guess it is not an issue with the application itself nor a specific distribution. just a matter of configuration and permissions